# Prove that $\angle A B C+\angle B C A+\angle C A B=0$ using directed angles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am reading EGMO and there author defines what a directed angle is and without giving any proof he listed all important properties of directed angle ,

I am  seriously not getting comfortable with directed angles and how to use them .
one of the properties that is listed is this

$$\angle A B C+\angle B C A+\angle C A B=0$$

Can someone give a proof of this fact?

Comment: why downvote ???

Comment: Are EGMO four more points?

Comment: no,its a book Euclidean geometry in maths olympiads by evan chen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think a directed angle as usual angle, except it encodes clockwise/anticlockwise in the sign and we always mod out 180 degrees.

Properly:

**Definition 1**: The directed angle $\angle(\ell,m)$ between two lines $\ell,m$ is the angle you rotate anticlockwise starting from $\ell$ and ending at $m$, modulo 180 degrees.

**Definition 2**: The directed angle $\angle ABC$ is defined as $\angle(\overline{AB},\overline{BC})$, where $\overline{AB}$ is the line $AB$, and similarly $\overline{BC}$.

So looking at your LHS: $\angle ABC$ is the (anticlockwise) angle turned to get from $\overline{AB}$ to $\overline{BC}$, $\angle BCA$ from $\overline{BC}$ to $\overline{CA}$, and finally $\angle CAB$ from $\overline{CA}$ to $\overline{AB}$.  So we start from line $AB$ and get back to line $AB$, so must be a multiple of 180 degrees, which we mod out.  So we get $0$ as in RHS.

Comment: The only angle you can rotate and still get the same line at the end as you begin are multiples of 180 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

In EGMO, directed angles are defined as angles $\mod {180}^{\circ}$, where $\measuredangle ABC$  to be positive if the vertices $A$, $B$, $C$
appear in clockwise order, and negative otherwise .

Note that in $\measuredangle ABC$, $\measuredangle BCA$, $\measuredangle CAB$ , the vertices are all either written in clockwise order or anticlockwise order .[why ?]

If they are all written in clockwise in clockwise order, then we have, $\measuredangle ABC+ \measuredangle BCA +\measuredangle CAB \equiv \angle A B C+\angle B C A+\angle C A B \equiv 180 \equiv 0 \mod 180^{\circ}$ [ by using the triangle sum property ]

If they are all written in anti-clockwise  order, then we have, $\measuredangle ABC+ \measuredangle BCA +\measuredangle CAB \equiv -\angle A B C-\angle B C A-\angle C A B \equiv -(\angle A B C+\angle B C A+\angle C A B)\equiv -180^{\circ} \equiv 0 \mod 180^{\circ}$ [ by using the triangle sum property ]

And hence, we have $\measuredangle ABC+ \measuredangle BCA +\measuredangle CAB \equiv 0 \mod 180^{\circ} \implies \measuredangle ABC+ \measuredangle BCA +\measuredangle CAB = 0 $.

Comment: thanks for replying, but can you give a illustration of some example that uses directed angles , because i myself have tried several times to understand the example given in book but i still did not understand how directed angle proves all configuration ....thankyou

Comment: Okay , I will give you some basic example ..but did you see notice how directed angles are helping to proves the 6 cyclic quads orthocentre configuration ? But first and foremost sis you understand what I wrote ?

Comment: sorry for late reply,yes i understand what you have wrote above.