# Is $\phi =\angle A"OB" = \measuredangle(AB,A"B")=\measuredangle(A'B',A"B")$? [Doubt]

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, rotations, geometric-transformation

Can someone clarify this doubt ?

We denote the spiral similarity by $S$, the rotation centered at $O$  with
angle $\phi$ by $\rho _O ,\phi$ , and the homothety centered at $O$ with ratio $k$ by $\chi _{ O, k}$ , then
$S _{O, k, \phi}$ = $\rho_O, \phi \circ \chi _{ O, k}$ .

Consider the following image :

[image]

We are given a triangle $ABC$ which is being dilated by a spiral symmetry $S$ centred at $O$ with ratio $k$ and and angle $\phi$ .

I noted that since angles are preserved in dilation and homothety, we get that $\Delta ABC \sim \Delta A"B"C" $.

Also $\Delta OAB \sim \Delta OA"B"$. And we have $\angle A"OB"=\angle AOB$ .

And we also have $\measuredangle(AB,A"B")=\measuredangle(A'B',A"B")$ (since $A'B'||AB$) .

But I couldn't understand how $\measuredangle(AB,A"B")=\measuredangle(A'B',A"B")=\phi$ . Isn't $\phi =\angle A"OB"$ ?

Here is the whole explanation of the book: [image]

Comment: spiral similarly is well explained in the book $\color{red}{\text{Euclidean Geometry In Mathematical Olympiads}}$.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya Thank you ! I will see through it too .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be $\phi = \angle A'OA''$.

Rotation takes $A'$ to $A''$ and $B'$ to $B''$ so it takes $A'B'$ to $A''B''$ so we have $$\angle (A''B'',A'B') = \phi$$

Since homothety takes $A$ to $A'$ and $B$ to $B'$ we have $AB||A'B'$, so it is obivously that $$\angle (A''B'',A'B') =\angle (A''B'',AB)$$

Comment: what does $\angle (A''B'',A'B') =\angle (A''B'',AB)$  ? isn't it  A"XA , where A"B" intersect at AB ?

Comment: If $a||b$ the $\angle (a,c)= \angle (b,c)$.

Comment: isn't $\phi =\angle A"OB"$ ?

Comment: No, it is $\angle A'OA''$. It is wrong in OP

Comment: oh, I see. But then I am not clear with the definition of $\angle (A''B'',A'B') $ , Can you define it once ?

Comment: It is angle between lines $A'B'$ and $A''B''$.

Comment: I am really sorry, but what does angles between two lines mean?

Comment: It is angle betweem vectors $\vec{A'B'}$ and $\vec{A''B''}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771986/prove-that-angle-a-b-c-angle-b-c-a-angle-c-a-b-0-using-directed-angles

Comment: Thankyou ! I was actually assumed that \phi= AOB . I guess that was my mistake. Thanks again!