# $\measuredangle (A''B'',A'B')" $ and $\angle (A''B'',A'B')"$?

Tags: geometry

I have been seeing this very frquently in olympiads question stating  "$\measuredangle (A''B'',A'B')"$ , where $A"B"$ and $AB$ are line segment.

Can someone explain me what it means with the help of a diagram ?

When I searched on net it showed "the directed angle between the lines AB and A"B" . " .

Also is there anything different in $\measuredangle (A''B'',A'B')" $ and $\angle (A''B'',A'B')"$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\angle A B C+\angle B C A+\angle C A B=0$ using directed angles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771986/prove-that-angle-a-b-c-angle-b-c-a-angle-c-a-b-0-using-directed-angles)

Comment: yes, thankyou !

Comment: You might also want to read [this](https://pregatirematematicaolimpiadejuniori.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/directed-angles.pdf)

Comment: oh.. such a great handout !

Comment: Years ago, I was surfing the internet for olympiad problems, and I came across Darij Grinberg's site, clicked on something and downloaded the entire website, where there were a huge lot of problems and their solutions worked out using directed lines and directed segments. [Here](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/geometry2.html) and [here](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/geometry.html)